# php pseudo-random distribution in a loop

Tags: php, loops, random

I have some code that generates a random output based on prior parameters from different arrays

Data setup:

```
$persons = array("Old", "Young", "Child");
$moods = array("neutral", "happy", "sad");
$newarray= "";

shuffle($persons );
$persons2 = array_merge(...array_fill(1, 92, $persons ));
$persons2 = $array = array_slice($persons2, 1, 30);

shuffle($moods);
$moods2 = array_merge(...array_fill(1, 92, $moods));
$moods2 = $array = array_slice($moods2, 1, 30);
```

The desired output is an if-loop that generates strings of equally many old, young, and child objects that are each an equal amount of neutral, happy, and sad - something like

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 30; $x++) {

$mood = $moods2[$x % (count($moods2))];
$person = $persons2 [$x % (count($persons2))];
$newarray .= "|".$person.",".$mood."|";

  }
```

The problem with this code is that it does not ensure that the moods "happy", "sad", "neutral" are combined evenly with the person categories "Old", "Young", "Child".
The desired output is something like

```
$newarray= "|Old,happy||Old,sad||Old,netrual||Young,happy||Young,sad||Young,netrual||Child,happy||Child,sad||Child,neutral|";
```

such that there is 30 iterations and the possible persons/moods combinations occur equally frequently.

Not that I would also like that final output to be randomly ordered and that the code should work even when changing the number of iterations of the for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate your cartesian product, then loop as many times as needed and grab the the next element in the shuffled array using circular index access (via modulus calculation).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VjkOE))

```
$persons = ["Old", "Young", "Child"];
$moods = ["neutral", "happy", "sad"];
$size = 30;

$cartesianStrings = [];
foreach($persons as $p) {
    foreach($moods as $m) {
        $cartesianStrings[] = $p . ' ' . $m;
    }
}

shuffle($cartesianStrings);
$cartesianSize = count($cartesianStrings);
for ($x = 0; $x <= $size; ++$x) {
    $result[] = '|' . $cartesianStrings[$x % $cartesianSize] . '|';
}
shuffle($result);
echo implode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create to set of all possible permutations of your input, then fill an array of the desired size with the set of permutations then shuffle it.

```php
<?php

$person = ['Old', 'Young', 'Child'];
$moods = ['neutral', 'happy', 'sad'];

// Create a buffer for our set of combinations
$cartesianProduct = [];

// Nested loop to create the total set of combinations
foreach($person as $currPerson)
{
    foreach($moods as $currMood)
    {
        // Create string representation of the combination
        $cartesianProduct[] = $currPerson.' '.$currMood;
    }
}

// Desired size of output array
$limit = 30;

// Buffer for the final output
$output = [];

// Start at a random point and keep track of where we are in the set of possible combinations
$cartIndex = array_rand($cartesianProduct);

// Loop until we have the desired buffer size
while (sizeof($output) < $limit)
{
    // Add the current input to the output and increment the input index
    $output[] = $cartesianProduct[$cartIndex++];

    // If we have reached the end of the input buffer, reset to zero
    if ($cartIndex == sizeof($cartesianProduct))
    {
        $cartIndex = 0;
    }
}

// Randomize the output buffer
shuffle($output);

// Let's look at the results...
print_r($output);
```

You can do this in a more generic and reusable way (and support any number of input sets, not just two) using a class to create the Cartesian product.

```php
<?php

class Cartesian
{
    public static function build($set)
    {
        if (!$set) {
            return [[]];
        }

        $subset = array_shift($set);
        $cartesianSubset = self::build($set);

        $result = [];
        foreach ($subset as $value)
        {
            foreach ($cartesianSubset as $p)
            {
                array_unshift($p, $value);
                $result[] = $p;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

// Input set - can by any number of "rows"
$input = [
    ['Old', 'Young', 'Child'],
    ['neutral', 'happy', 'sad']
];

// Build our total set of permutations
$cartesianProduct = Cartesian::build($input);

// Desired size of output array
$limit = 30;

// Buffer for the final output
$output = [];

// Start at a random point and keep track of where we are in the set of possible combinations
$cartIndex = array_rand($cartesianProduct);


// Loop until we have the desired buffer size
while (sizeof($output) < $limit)
{
    // Get the current input and increment the input index
    $currProduct = $cartesianProduct[$cartIndex++];
    
    // Add a string representation of the current entry to the output 
    $output[] = $currProduct[0].' '.$currProduct[1];

    // If we have reached the end of the input buffer, reset to zero
    if ($cartIndex == sizeof($cartesianProduct))
    {
        $cartIndex = 0;
    }
}

// Randomize the output buffer
shuffle($output);

// Let's look at the results...
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Not sure why you would create a class with 1 static method.

Comment: The class is so you don't have to rewrite the method in multiple places if you need to use it more than once, and the method is static so you don't have to instantiate a class that doesn't have state.

Comment: This is close, but I am looking for an output that is a "" string, not an array. How could I modulate the above to achieve this?

Comment: There are a number of ways you could do that. I've updated both examples to show how.

Comment: closer still but the output is still an array (of length $limit) instead of a text-string. Would you also know how to modify the code if there's a third set of parameters that should only be applied in some sub-cases? For instance $tears = ['none', 'few', 'some', 'many']; where all instances with mood 'neutral' should have 'none' tears, and all instances of mood 'happy' or 'sad' should have 'few', 'some', or 'many' tears also evenly distributed.